# get Result in getCellFormula

Tags: java, excel

I am reading Excel with java, In my Cell I have a formula, but I want get the result -> 20.000 or 2.154, etc, but I get ->

### IF(F2="Buy",+(H2-G2+1)*I2,+(H2-G2+1)*I2*(-1))

---

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        stringValue = cell.getCellFormula();
    break;
```

....

the problem is that I could't calculated this formula, because I read the excel cell a cell then ... h2-g2... my code doesn't know this...

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

how can I get the value of cell ?

```
Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: ---> IF(F2="Buy",+(H2-G2+1)*I2,+(H2-G2+1)*I2*(-1))
Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: ----> IF(F2="Buy",+(H2-G2+1)*I2,+(H2-G2+1)*I2*(-1))
```

Thanks!!

EDIT , 
I changed ->

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
    stringValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
break;
```

result -> `5.475E7` this result is bad, my Excel have `54.750.000 visually`

Comment: So you're getting `5.475E7` and instead want `54.750.000`?  I would think that's just a formatting issue, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you get is correct so you're almost there, it's just not formatted as you expect.

Try:

```
    String stringValue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: thanks Amila, It is nearly correct because I have 1 problem ...when return  -  in my Excel, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell.